# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre las etiquetas HTML <strong> y <b> y entre <em> e <i>?

Tags: html, html5, accesibilidad

Como ya sabemos, las etiquetas `<strong>` y `<b>` producen ¿el mismo efecto visual? en los documentos HTML:

- **negritas con `<b>`**
- **negritas con `<strong>`**.

Lo mismo ocurre con `<em>` e `<i>`, las cuales presentan texto en cursivas:

- *cursivas con `<i>`*
- *cursivas con `<em>`*

Pero... ¿hay diferencias entre `<strong>` y `<b>` así como entre `<em>` e `<i>`?

¿Se recomienda por algún motivo usar una u otra según casos específicos?

Comment: La respuesta hacia la primera interrogante sobre las diferencias entre **strong** y **b**, se encuentran en un apartado de StackOverflow en inglés, te dejo [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271743/whats-the-difference-between-b-and-strong-i-and-em).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

La única diferencia es la semántica aplicada, principalmente a partir de HTML5, la cual es importante y recomendada para la **accesibilidad** y tal vez para SEO (aún si no puedo probar esto).

[Ver especificación de `<strong>`.](http://w3c.github.io/html-reference/strong.html#strong)

[Ver especificación de `<b>`.](http://w3c.github.io/html-reference/b.html#b)

[Ver especificación de `<em>`.](http://w3c.github.io/html-reference/em.html#em)

[Ver especificación de `<i>`.](http://w3c.github.io/html-reference/i.html#i)

---

Básicamente, `<strong>` se debería utilizar cuando se va a hacer énfasis en un texto, por ejemplo, algo que debería leerse en voz alta, para que los lectores (o quienes escuchan) lo tengan muy en cuenta.

`<b>` se debería usar para el aspecto visual únicamente, si el texto entre dichas etiquetas no necesariamente es más importante o no requiere más énfasis que el resto, pero queremos que esté en *bold* por el motivo que consideremos, entonces es la etiqueta adecuada.

---

Lo mismo ocurre con `<em>` e `<i>`, siendo `<em>` el elemento que agrega el toque semántico, e `<i>` el del aspecto visual únicamente.

---

`<strong>` y `<em>` aplican tipos de énfasis distintos, siendo (a partir de HTML5) `<strong>` un énfasis o importancia fuerte y `<em>` un énfasis que establece un aspecto particular de una frase, como puede ser un extranjerismo o una traducción.

Comment: ¡Excelente respuesta! No vendría mal una pequeña nota con lo que dice la especificación de cada una, traducida, ya que contiene detalles interesantes que no conocía, y creo que no soy el único. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 9):

Complementando la [respuesta de Shaz](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/77704/42433):

`b` y `i` son estilos únicamente, es decir, se utilizan para fines estéticos o de presentación, pero sin hacer diferencia en la fuerza o énfasis que la palabra o frase estilizada puedan tener sobre el texto completo.

`strong` y `em`, en cambio, marcan una diferencia en la fuerza o énfasis que se quiere dar a una palabra o frase sobre el texto completo.

En un navegador tradicional la diferencia no se percibe, ya que las etiquetas `strong` y `em` se estilizan como `b` e `i` respectivamente. Sin embargo en dispositivos más pequeños en ocasiones todo el texto se muestra en negritas (e.g. un *Kindle* con tamaño de letra grande) y, por ende, interpretan esas etiquetas de otra forma (e.g. subrayados) para indicar el énfasis que tiene esa palabra.

Otro uso común es para dispositivos con apoyo de voz (utilizados comunmente por personas con problemas visuales) donde una etiqueta `b` es ignorada pero una etiqueta `strong` no lo es (i.e. la entonación de la voz cambia).

Comment: Gracias. Ignoraba lo de los dispositivos pequeños. Interesante​.

Answer (score 1):

En el caso de `<strong>` y `<b>` aunque aparentemente el diseño sea igual, la etiqueta `<strong>` resalta la importancia en el texto. Por ejemplo, en temas de SEO, los buscadores dan más importancia a una negrita con `<strong>`, sin embargo, tampoco es bueno abusar de ella.