# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre <i> con <em> y <b> con <strong>?

Tags: html

Hay etiquetas que parecieran tener el mismo efecto en el usuario por ejemplo `<strong>` y `<b>`, además de `<i>` y `<em>`.

Estas son las que he encontrado, pero supongo que hay mas como estos casos.

¿Podría alguien aclararme la diferencia de estas en la practica?

Comment: ¿Has investigado o leido al respecto?

Comment: Similar: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/77699/cu%C3%A1l-es-la-diferencia-entre-las-etiquetas-html-strong-y-b-y-entre-em-e-i/77711

Answer (score 0):

`<strong>` debe usarse para elementos que tienen mayor importancia (strong importance), podria ser mensajes de error o advertencia, los navegadores tipicamente lo muestran como letra BOLD (negrita) pero no hay garantia de que siempre se muestre así.

`<b>` Se usa para usar la letra BOLD de manera explicita sin indicar que el elemento al que se le aplica sea un contenido con mayor importancia (como si lo hace strong)

Aca tambien te explican `<em>` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/strong

Answer (score 0):

**La diferencia es meramente de SEO**

La etiqueta `<strong>` se usa para resaltar textos que contengan reservada importancia y `<b>` para resaltar textos sin importancia

```html
<p><strong>Este texto tendrá mayor importancia en SEO</strong></p>
<p><b>Este texto solo está resaltado</b></p>
```

Pasa de la misma manera con `<em>` y con `<i>`, `<em>` es para poner textos que tengan importancia en itálica e `<i>` es solo para poner textos en itálicas

---

**`<i>` y `<b>` son estilos**

Dichas etiquetas son solo estilos, es decir que son explícitos, por defecto los navegadores tienen esto

```
b {
    font-weight:bold;
}

i {
    font-style:italic;
}
```

Por lo que los navegadores interpretarán `<b>` e `<i>` con las reglas aplicadas respectivamente

Y con diferencia, `<em>` y `<strong>` son semánticos, lo que significa que especifican que el texto debe ser **fuerte o enfatizado** de alguna manera, generalmente en negrita y cursiva, pero permiten que el estilo real sea controlado por CSS. Por lo tanto, son la prioridad en las páginas web modernas.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!